# are there RAID configuration defaults for storage devices?

Tags: raid, storage

Are there certain **default** configurations within storage devices (**such as IBM System Storage DS5020 Express**) for RAID 5 and RAID 10? [tried to find if there were by reading whitepaper for DS5020, but couldn't find any info on this]

Comment: With a gazillion references readily available describing RAID configurations in detail posting this question displays extreme laziness.

Comment: I did not find any docs on RAID 10 configurations. Can you please link me to some of them.

Comment: Further, I did not find any docs concerning the DS5020 Express storage system and if it has default configurations for RAID 5, and RAID 10..... maybe you can give me some links...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "default" since there is no meaningful one-size-fits-all setting to default to. There is the [***"IBM Midrange System Storage Hardware Guide"***](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247676.html) which provides some guidelines and walkthroughs using the *DS Storage Manager* for a number of configurations. Also, RedBooks are available on this topic like the [***"System Storage DS5000 Series Implementation and Best Practices Guide"***](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpieces/abstracts/sg248024.html?Open&pdfbookmark).

You will rather not find the term "RAID 10" in IBM documentation. What you end up doing is creating a "RAID 1" array with the number of devices you need to have in *Storage Manager*. From the previously mentioned [*Implementation and Best Practices Guide*](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpieces/abstracts/sg248024.html?Open&pdfbookmark):

> **Note:** RAID 1 is actually implemented only as RAID 10 [...] on the DS5000 storage subsystem products.

Note that unlike the IBM RAID storage controllers for xSeries servers, the DS line does not support [RAID 1e](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/eserver/v1r2/index.jsp?topic=/diricinfo/fqy0_craid1e.html) which would allow using an odd number of drives in a 50%-redundancy configuration. Also interesting to know is that the IBM DS 3000/4000/5000 series have been designed and manufactured by LSI (now LSI-Engenio and a division of NetApp) and are OEM-labeled by IBM, so documentation for the [LSI Engenio 4900 would mostly apply to the DS 5020 as well](http://www.storagenewsletter.com/news/systems/ibm-system-storage-ds5020-disk-system).